# Is there a name or notation for "stitching" intervals together?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, interval-arithmetic

Suppose I have a sequence of intervals $I_k = [a_k, b_k]$ for $k = 1, \ldots, n$. They may overlap each other.

I want to define a combination $\mathcal{I}$ of these intervals that is not quite a union, and not quite a direct product, but more like stitching them together like a quilt. An element of $\mathcal{I}$ would be a pair $(k, t)$ where $t \in [a_k, b_k]$.

Is this already a thing? Is there a common name or notation for it?

Comment: Looks like the disjoint union of the intervals.

Comment: I think that's exactly what I'm after. I'll use $\sqcup$ to denote it.

Comment: Correct - that is the definition of disjoint union. If you have heard of "category theory", this is the "direct sum" of your intervals in the category of sets and maps between sets. (And the fact that the original sets were intervals, or that the indexing set was $\mathbb N$, are both irrelevant).

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it would be better to use $\sqcup$ or $\oplus$ to denote it. I'm familiar with category theory but it's been a while since I learned it, so I didn't make the connection.